# What causes some web game engines work in "slow mo" mode instead of reducing FPS but continuing to show the true time/tick state of things?

Tags: godot, game-loop, webgl, cocos3d

I used game engines that are capable of cross-platform export: Cocos Creator, Godot, Unity, others.

Some game engines have this thing, called "physics update" or "fixed update". Those are methods where the "true" calculation should occur. Meaning if your game domain logic says - this bullet should fly with this precise speed and not less not more - you put this code into the "physics update" method of object. So even when FPS of game is low, bullet will change position as it should.

I assume there is some time/tick calculation done inside those methods to ensure expected behaviour.

But some engines lack this feature. Like Cocos Creator. There is only "update" method.
And when game runs on slow machines in browsers - game goes into this "slow mo" mode instead of "true but low fps" mode.

Why does this happen? Some people say that it's impossible to gain "true physics process" method in the browser, but I saw one in Godot 3.5 web export. You have low FPS but everything moves with the speed designed in the editor, not the speed browser allows. FPS is low of course, but not slow moving stuff. That is, if you put your important code into this "physics process" method, of course.

Comment: follow up question, if you've used Unity, Godot, etc. Why use Cocos? If it's lacking this feature doesn't it make sense to just use the others instead. There is a reason Unity and Unreal are the most popular engines and it's mostly due to the range of features. Perhaps Cocos just lacks this feature.

Comment: @Pow because Cocos Creator is best in terms of engine usability -> web export. It covers audio problems, safari problems, resizing problems, size of final build (it really matters).

And if I would like to use game engine for mobile/desktop/console - I would pick Godot if I am not commanded by my superiors at workplace to do otherwise. I have experience in Unity, but I like to use Godot and support it as much as I can with issues, finding bugs etc.

Comment: Gotcha, unfortunately I can't help you, but perhaps you could look at creating your own fixed timestep?

Comment: @Pow this is interesting! I am not familiar with whole fixed timestep thing. Will try to learn about it. Maybe that's what other engines are doing... Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple way to get this slow-mo effect is if you have a variable rate update and no delta time correction to make it "framerate independent". For example if each update you say:

```
position.x += 1
```

Then you're moving right one pixel or unit per frame. The more frames per second, the more movement happens in that time, so action speeds up (though you can limit this by sleeping some excess time away instead of updating/rendering as fast as the hardware will go). If the frame rate dips down below your target pace, the action goes into slow-mo.

So most games scale their movement by elapsed time (`position.x += speed * deltaTime`), or implement a fixed time step like the "fixed update" you describe, which are decoupled from rendering speed.

But you can get this slow-mo even with a fixed update based system, if that fixed step gets sufficiently overloaded.

In Unity for example, if computing a single frame takes longer than [Time.maximumDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-maximumDeltaTime.html) wall clock seconds, that elapsed time is clipped down to the given max. At that point, even code in `FixedUpdate` will start to run behind real time, and the simulation doesn't just render more choppily: game state updates start getting that "slow mo" effect you describe.

[I explain this in more depth in this older answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192414/39518).

You can imagine the engine's game loop being implemented something a bit like this pseudo-code:

```
Tick() {
    now = GetCurrentTime()
    deltaTime = Min(now - startOfLastFrame, maxDeltaTime)
    startOfLastFrame = now

    accumulator += deltaTime

    while (accumulator >= fixedTimeStep) {
        // Run zero or more game state updates back-to-back,
        // each representing a consistent slice of simulation time.
        gameTime += fixedTimeStep
        FixedUpdate(fixedTimeStep)
        accumulator -= fixedTimeStep
    }

    // Tick anything that's not gameplay/physics sensitive
    // (like UI) just once per rendered frame, scaling
    // their animation progress by the full time elapsed.
    VariableRateUpdate(deltaTime)

    // Compute interpolation ratio - how much progress
    // have we made from the last FixedUpdate to the next?
    // This can be used to draw objects in an intermediate
    // state to hide judder from fixed ticks being mismatched
    // to the frame rate.
    alpha = accumulator/fixedTimeStep
    Render(alpha)
}
```

As long as we can complete all those steps - potentially multiple `FixedUpdate()` ticks, a `VariableRateUpdate()`, and issuing commands to `Render()` the frame - in less than `deltaTime` wall clock seconds, the displayed state of the simulation keeps up with real time. The faster we do it, the better our framerate, but we have a range in which we can soak differences in hardware/code performance without changing gameplay simulation outcomes and the speed things move relative to real time.

But once there's enough load anywhere in this system - in `FixedUpdate()`, `VariableRateUpdate()`, or `Render()` - to cause a single frame to take longer than our `maxDeltaTime`, we clip away the excess real time to keep the execution time bounded, using something like this:

```
deltaTime = Min(now - startOfLastFrame, maxDeltaTime)
```

Now we're simulating fewer seconds in the game than actually occurred out in the real world over the same interval, and the game appears to go in slow mo.

Without this, you can get a snowballing effect, where one long frame means we need to run more `FixedUpdate()` ticks in the next frame to catch up to real time. But running more `FixedUpdate()` ticks takes more time, so that frame gets longer too, so we need to run more ticks again... This can cause the framerate to get worse and worse, and transform a momentary hitch (like a loading spike) to stretch into a long period of sluggishness until the game finally manages to catch up to where it should have been without that hiccup.

Enforcing a `maxDeltaTime` means that we "make the best of a bad situation" after such a loading spike. We accept discarding some time, so our simulation is now "in the past", but then we keep ticking it forward at a normal rate from there, turning that snowballing sluggishness into (hopefully) just a momentary hitch.

This kind of slow-mo will eventually happen to any engine, if you put enough workload into `FixedUpdate()` (or their equivalents) that the time spent processing it all nears or exceeds the duration of the fixed time step. At that point, there's no way to catch up to real time: every time you try, you just dig yourself even deeper into time debt.

So, it could be that each of these engines is managing its fixed time steps in very similar ways, and it's just that some of them sit closer to this edge of inevitable slowdown - either because of...

- differences in efficiency of their internals (a slow game engine, running in a slow language like JavaScript in the browser, will naturally be easier to bog down this way than one that's better-optimized for the game you're making)
- or the engine/game's `maxDeltaTime` (or equivalent) is tuned more tightly or more loosely (say, based on different estimates of the target hardware/experience or the complexity of game code they're designed to support).

Comment: Interesting point about spike behaviour.  Presumably for some kinds of games, it's better to have the simulation slow down than to continue full speed without the user being able to clearly see what's happening and respond to it.

Comment: This can also be done intentionally; see EVE Online's [time dilation](https://www.eveonline.com/news/view/introducing-time-dilation-tidi).