# FixedUpdate in Unity

Tags: unity, physics

I am trying to test my project for different discretization levels of a game object.
For this I use a metric to compare the dynamics of the object for different discretization (compare the positions). In order to make this work, I use fixed update to write down the positions of each update (as this simulates the physics frame rate independent, and therefore makes it comparable for different discretization/ needs of computing power).
But when writing the positions to a file, I noticed, that after e.g. 1 minute I would expect 1000 updates to have been written to the file for each discretization.
This is not the case for all levels of discretization.   Once the discretization is very fine, the number of updates written to the file (that is constant for a rough discretization) drops off and gets smaller for each further discretization.
What could be the reason for this? I was thinking, if the time step is to small and therefore at some point it gets "caught up" by real time and therefore the writing to the file stops? Or could there be other reasons for this?
The discretization works as the following:

- The outline of the game object can be approximately described by using basic volume elements (such as spheres and cubes...).
  -The dynamics of the game object should get more approximate the more refined this discretization is (the more basic volumes model the game object).
- In my case, I double the amount of basic volumes used for each discretization level --> the amount of prefabs used doubles for each iteration.

I run this discretization via a python loop (so I change the amount of volumes from within this loop) and a build unity project, therefore I am not sure, if using the profiler of unity would work/ help.
Or is there a better/ other solution than to choose a higher time step for the fixed update (a higher time step would cause other problems)
I am very grateful for any idea how to investigate this furtherly.

Comment: After one minute _of game time_, not after one minute of wall clock time. If Unity can't execute enough FixedUpdates in a given period, the game time slows down to allow the calculations to catch up.

Comment: @Basic Thank you for your answer. I am not sure, if I understand correctly, what the consequences of this could be. Would this mean, that if I simply let the build project run for a longer time, the calculations of the fixedUpdate will still be performed and just take longer to get written to the file, even if they are behind the realtime at a certain point (if this is the case)? Also, how can I find out, if the fixedupdate calculations time overtakes the realtime and causes this issue?

Comment: I've written some explanations of the relationship between the fixed time step, simulation time, and wall clock time [in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/132933/39518) and [in this other answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192414/39518), which may help you understand what happens when the processing load gets too heavy for the game scripts or physics simulation to keep up with real time.

Comment: Please also consider using whitespace to make your question not one unbroken wall of text.

Comment: @DMGregory I am not sure, what this means for a simulation: " Unity will stop running fixed steps and cap the simulation as far as it got this frame, resuming next frame". So e.g. if I have a fixed time step of 0.02, and the time to calculate each fixed update is 0.03, then Unity would always be behind real time. But now I am wondering, how the catching up process actually works? Will the game time be slowed down to 2/3 of real time, in order for the fixed updates to be able to catch up? How does Time.maximumDeltaTime achieve this?(https://johnaustin.io/articles/2019/fix-your-unity-timestep)

Comment: I explicitly cover that in the first link. At the default 0.333 max delta time, any excess wall clock time elapsed beyond a third of a second is banked for the future. The rest of the frame proceeds as though only a third of a second had elapsed, and only 16-17 FixedUpdates will be run per frame. If each one takes 0.03 seconds, then each frame will take over 0.51 wall clock seconds to process, advancing in-game time by 17 * 0.02 = 0.34 seconds. So your game runs at about 2/3 speed (possibly slower if rendering and other frame work add significantly beyond the fixed update cost).

Comment: If your FixedUpdate keeps costing more time to run than the wall clock time it's meant to represent, *it will never catch up*. The only way to catch up and return to normal speed is for the FixedUpdate cost to fall below the wall clock time.